# GridView RowUpdating not getting new data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When trying to update GridView data, it successfully runs, but it gets the old data instead of the data you type in the textboxes.

This is what I have:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
        string phone = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
        string email = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
        int contactId = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text);
        objLogic.UpdateContact(name, phone, email, contactId);  //passes values to SQL to update database
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and

```
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = objLogic.LoadClient();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "clientId";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = objLogic.LoadContacts(Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

For example, the current data is:

name: Blake, phone: 123-234-3456, email: test@test.com, contactId: 22

I type in new data:

name: John, phone: 555-555-5555, email: test2@test2.com, contactId: 22

Data that ends up in the database:

name: Blake, phone: 123-234-3456, email: test@test.com, contactId: 22

Comment: How is your GridView1.DataSource set?

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Mike, I added my PageLoad which is where the datasource is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = objLogic.LoadClient();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "clientId";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        BindGrid();
    }
 }

protected void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = objLogic.LoadContacts(Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Every time the page posts back you are rebinding the grid. Move the binding of the grid into a separate function. After you do the row updating, rebind the grid.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string name = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
    string phone = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
    string email = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
    int contactId = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text);
    objLogic.UpdateContact(name, phone, email, contactId);  //passes values to SQL to update database
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGrid();
}
```

When you edit you must call BindGrid too.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //GridView1.DataBind(); this is meaningless, you have not set a DataSource
    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: I implemented this and when I click the 'Edit' button, my gridview just disappears.  You know why I would do that?

Comment: Because, when you edit the grid (fire _RowEditing), you need to rebind the grid. I have edited my reply.

Comment: thanks Martin Smellworse & @sr28, I got it working! Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. Others had pointed you in the right direction, I just filled in the gaps.

Answer (score 4):

When you raise the RowUpdating event your basically getting the values BEFORE the GridView updates the row. This is basically so you can cancel the update operation. To get what you've type in I think you need to get the new values (the Dictionary e.NewValues() in your case).

In your case you can use it something like this (assuming name, phone and email are what they're called in your gridview):

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry de in e.NewValues())
{
    string name = de.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "name").Value;
    string phone = de.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "phone").Value;
    string email = de.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "email").Value;
}
```

NOTE: If you're simply using this to get the values typed in to update your database then you're better of binding the datagrid and use the value after that to ensure you definitely have the same values in the datagrid as to what you put into the database. Alternatively, use the RowUpdated event instead of the RowUpdating event.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but do you mind giving an example of how I would use this? The MSDN link confuses me a little.

Comment: @Prokzy - sorry, was initially doing it for itemupdating not row. Now fixed by adding the foreach.

Comment: The way he has it written will get the values written into the textboxes.

Comment: @sr28 thanks for the help.  When I use your example I get this, http://s28.postimg.org/5uc5d8hpn/Untitled.png

Comment: You REALLY don't need to do this. See my answer below.

Comment: @Prokzy - updated, though not tested. However, as Martin says you don't need to do this if all you're doing is simply getting the new values put in your data grid to then update your database. As stated at the beginning, this is something you do to get the values BEFORE the gridview updates, such as if you want to cancel the operation.

Answer (score 3):

The most prevalent reason is that we usually forgot to check the postbacks in the Page Load event.
check the post-back, then the problem will be removed.

```
if (! IsPostBack)
{
    readData();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, and I forgotten to put the bindgrid inside ( ! IsPostBack). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Prokzy` I have just your example on my side and doing something like this worked fine for me. notice the DataSource portion. I have a DataSet instantiated as aDataSet btw

```
    protected void GridView1_GridViewPageEventArgs e(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataSource = aDataset;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call LoadContacts again and reassign GridView1.DataSource after the database is updated.  Currently, the DataSource is not being updated - and is just using the collection that was retrieved prior to the row update.